# Transfer websites to another server without downtime

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

As we know when we change nameserver to any website it take 24hr to active and happen downtime to the website, So how I can transfer Websites to another server without downtime

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because the author does not show a level of technical understanding or appropriate due diligence in researching the topic that the community judges as being a minimum barrier to participate.

Answer (score 4):

If you change your DNS entries to point to a new server, the older cached entries will continue to hit your old server. You don't have to worry about downtime as long as both servers are still up and running.